# Why do I have a purple key?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

Ever since visiting Davy Jones' Locker, this thing showed up in the upper left:

[image]

What does it mean?  How did I get one filled? How do I fill/get the rest?

Comment: Whatever it is, I just died and it's still there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Davy Jones locker has 4 keys you need to collect before the path to the boss opens up. A recent bug in the latest build has caused the menu showing those keys to never go away (it's supposed to disappear once you leave the dungeon). 
You can find the official forum post for the build that introduced the bug [here](https://forums.wildshadow.com/node/156789).

As far as I can tell, there's no known fix for it right now.

Comment: Ah!  This explains why I didn't have a quest indicator!  The key is gone now.  Thanks!